# Twitter-Bootstrap Datepicker - Showing last day of month

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datepicker

I have a Twitter-Bootstrap datepicker.

```
$('#PeriodBeginDatepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    minViewMode: 1, // 1 for months
    maxViewMode: 2, // 2 for years
    autoclose: true,
    toggleActive: true
})
.on("show", function(event) {
        var year = $("th.datepicker-switch").eq(1).text();  // 3 matches
});
```

**OR**

```
  $('#PeriodBeginDatepicker').datepicker({ 
        format: "mm/01/yyyy",
        autoclose: true,
        toggleActive: true
    });
```

What I am trying to achieve is to display the last date of month,
instead of the first.

Comment: can you produce a graphic example of what you need? I seriously don't understand

Comment: @Sampgun when i run the above code when i select the date picker for may 2018 and  june 2018  i am getting the first date of any month and any year  i.e, 05/01/2018, 06/01/2018 but i am looking for the  last date of any month and any year, irrespective of any date selected should be last of the selected month i.e, 05/31/2018, 06/30/2018

Comment: Please help its any urgent requirement

Comment: Put your code in a fiddle and I'll take a look.

Comment: Or you could simply add HTML and script tags in your code above to make it runnable.